# How can I prevent tissues from falling back into the box?

Tags: home, personal-care, bathroom

I get the larger size boxes of tissues (210 count). Once the box of tissues only has about 1/3 of the tissues remaining, the top tissue isn’t very close to the opening of the box, so gravity usually pulls it back down into the box. If you pull it through enough so that it doesn’t fall back in, then it gets pulled away from the next tissue in line enough that it separates, and when you pull the tissue out later on, it doesn’t draw the next one up through the opening.  Is there a simple way to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 4):

My solution to the tissues not popping up is an easy one. When you get Amazon packages that have the little air filled bags that tear apart, simply open one end of the box and stick 3 to 4 of those bags under the tissues to take up the space and a piece of tape to secure the end. Reusable next time. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I just thought of this and tried it and it seemed to do the trick.  You might have to play with the length of the slit and make it longer but works well and you can keep the box just as it is[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't normally share this with anyone; but, your relentless nagging forced me to divulge one of my favourite secret family tissue-dispensing life hacks.

Hang or suspend the box of tissues under a shelf or cupboard upside-down—with the opening facing downward.
**Pull down** to dispense a tissue — *in a manner similar to the paper towel dispensers found in many hospitality rest rooms*.

In addition to working until the very end of the box, you sacrifice no counter-top space

Comment: XD that’s a good one... I do use that technique in my workshop but it’s not really an option in places like our half-bath.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the question, because I'd never gone looking for a solution before.

1. This one will work for me. Will attach in bathroom and store 1/2 empty tissue boxes (from other places in the house) in linen closet until ready for 'flip' option in the holder. Can also sit on holder in regular position, of course.

[https://www.amazon.com/Flip-Tissue-Holder-Wall-Mounted/dp/B07B4JQL93](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B4JQL93)

[image: Wall Mount Flip Box Holder]

2. This type also available for the square tissue boxes:

[https://www.amazon.com/Camco-Tissue-Cabinets-Dispenses-Downward/dp/B000EDOTCI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000EDOTCI)

Answer (score 1):

[image: This really works. Cut along red dashes. Be sure to cut two slits as shown to lock the tube together. Feel free to share and post this image anywhere you think it could be useful.]

This really works. Cut along red dashes. Be sure to cut two slits as shown to lock the tube together. Feel free to share and post this image anywhere you think it could be useful. Cybergoal.com created this image and provides it for all uses free of charge.

Comment: Welcome! Do you own the picture? It shows a copyright notice and using it without proper attribution is considered plagiarism and not acceptable here. See [How to reference material written by others](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for more information. This of course includes encouraging others to redistribute the material. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for editing the source of the image into your answer.  I can't find anything on their website that offers that image free of charge.

Comment: I am the owner of JS Enterprises and Cybergoal.com is my website. As such, I give

Answer (score 1):

[image: This version has a clearly stated copyright and its ownership details.The idea really works. I'll be posting an alternate method soon as well!]
This version has a clearly stated copyright and its ownership details.The idea really works. I'll be posting an alternate method soon as well!

Answer (score 0):

as you pull each tissue out, right as it's finishing coming out, put a twist into it with your wrist.

This 'crimps' the remaining tissue sheet, thus preventing it from easily falling back into the box.

I've done this for years - though it does take a tiny amount of practice to get correct...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the second of two possible solutions for the soul-shattering, mental anguish of the consumer version of the 210-count OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer's) facial-tissue dispenser failure.

Step #1. Deftly, and with great care and craftsmanship, open the bottom box flaps of your attractive generously proportioned facial tissue dispenser when it is at or near the point of failure. Try to do this in a manner such that its flaps can be closed.

Step #2. Place a spacer to fill the vacant space left by the previously consumed tissues. The spacer will boost the level of the tissues into the safety zone where tissue dispenser failure is minimal, hopefully non-existent.
[image]
Step #3. Close the container bottom and place it back where it will be of some convenience. The sheer mass of the dispenser will keep the bottom closed, or you can use some tape.

When the tissue level drops to the failure level, additional spacer(s) can be used to compensate for the drop in efficiency with use.

You should only need a couple of (70 count) spacers; so, make a couple when you make the first one. Save-em. They will be re-useable from one tissue box to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a ***change in tissue format***.

(This is the third of two possible answers.)

Tissue comes in two formats:

- Cut folded squares in a cubic cardboard dispenser.
- Serrated sections in a spool on a cardboard tube.

Using the tissue in roll format avoids the accessibility difficulty with tissue dispenser failure you described with the folded square format in your probing question. It is interesting to note that in this form a dispenser is not necessary although different types are available which are portable or affixed to a wall.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just hold the box upside down while pulling out the tissue. Remember not to pull too quickly. A slower pull brings the next tissue along nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Where I live, the tissues box has an "elevator" on the bottom - really just perforations which allow you to push in two panels which help to lift the remaining tissues towards the top.

Here is what I found on a quick search for it: https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/58dqzk/this_tissue_box_has_a_tissue_elevator_to_lift_up/

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using tissue boxes, use the ones that hang, it would be easy to pull.

Comment: Hi Raghu, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE. Please explain your answer more fully and perhaps you can find an illustration to clarify what you had in mind to help answer the question even better.